# Terraform: Duplicate names are not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform-provider-aws

I have Terraform with Workspaces. When I run Terraform my resources are created but when I change the Workspace then the errors below appear because the resources are already created:

```
Error: creating IAM Role: EntityAlreadyExists (role): Role with name env-role already exists.
Error: creating IAM Policy (policy): EntityAlreadyExists: A policy called env-with-policy already exists. Duplicate names are not allowed.
```

These are the resources:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "payload_for_lambda" {
  name = "${var.iam_role_name}"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" {

  name        = "${var.iam_policy_name}"
  path        = "/"
  description = "AWS IAM Policy for managing aws lambda role"
  policy      = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": [
       "logs:CreateLogGroup",
       "logs:CreateLogStream",
       "logs:PutLogEvents"
     ],
     "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
     "Effect": "Allow"
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}
```

I run both terraform init and terraform apply commands to apply the changes.

Is there a way Terraform to recognize the existing resources for my Workspaces and don't try to create them every time?

Regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that Terraform knows that the resources are unique (this is handled by the statefile) but you are using explicit names and this causes conflicts in AWS:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" {
   name        = "${var.iam_policy_name}"
   ...
```

So the errors you are seeing come from AWS and not from Terraform.

You can add a resource like this:

```
resource "random_string" "suffix" {
  length = 16
  special = false
}
```

First run terraform init

Then you can add this suffix to all resources that require a unique name:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" {
   name        = "${var.iam_policy_name}-${random_string.suffix.result}"
   ...
```

Upon replanning, Terraform will see that the random string is already generated (it is in your statefile so it does not change).

Instead of using a random string, you can also use a prefix or suffix that you know is unique in the environment (ie. workspace-a, workspace-b).

Comment: A random suffix works but wouldn't say it is a good idea. It is better to use suffix stated in a var files for the different workspaces.

Comment: Yes I just saw he used workspaces, I've edited the post to reflect that!

Comment: PS - The error that he is getting suggests that his statefile is out of sync with his AWS environment (because if you change the name of the profile or some other non-changeable attribute, it would recreate the policy / role instead of trying to create it).

Comment: It is due to terraform workspaces.
Workspaces in Terraform are simply independently managed state files.

Comment: Thank you Alex. The random suffix is not bad idea but each time when I run terraform apply new role and policy will be create. I know the error is because the resource name must be unique but I wonder if there is a way Terraform to check if the resource exists or not and skip the creation if exists. Right now we have 3 Workspaces (dev,prod and staging) and we updating them every day.

Comment: Hi @Ivo, so basically the problem is that you guys need to have a single shared state file to work from. If you move your statefile to S3, then Terraform knows the resources are already created and won't create them again: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3

Comment: Didn't get that was your understanding and goal. But I would say it is simple you split your TF file. You have one with IAM part and the other with the workspace resources. In all places I have been this is how we have done it.

Comment: Alex, moving the state files from local to S3 is planned but not done yet. I will check today when we plan to move the state files remotely and will test later. I didn't know this will solve the problem but seems to be good idea. 

@Erik, thank you very much for your advice. Can you share with me link to topic how to split the state file or show me? I can try that until I'm allowed to use the s3 for backend.

Comment: https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/7955227415059-How-to-Split-State-Files

Comment: Alex, unfortunately creating S3 backend and updating the resource for another Workspace (ex. prod or dev) doesn't work. On the stage where my lambda function have to be updated it stucks for 5 minutes and don't want to continue: aws_lambda_function.lambda: Still creating... [4m30s elapsed]  with error. 

`Error: creating Lambda Function (lambda-aliases): operation error Lambda: CreateFunction, https response error StatusCode: 409, RequestID: 95d1-f59243844a1c, ResourceConflictException: Function already exist: lambda-aliases`

Comment: This error is because the Lambda is already there (but Terraform does not know about it), there are two solutions: 1) Delete the Lambda function and retry 2) [Import the lambda function to the statefile](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state)

Comment: Unfortunately both advices doesn't work for me. I deleted and recreated the test lambda but I'm still getting the same results. Importing the lambda function will be painful when you have 200 lambdas.  Thank you for all advices I will check again in internet. 

@Erik, splitting the TF file didn't help me too.

Comment: How did you split? You need to move the aim part into a new TF file with a own state file. This state file should own the created resource you have issue with. And due to that this resource is now a separate state file you should be able to run your other TF file without this resource.

Comment: @Erik, I followed this article from internet how to split my tfstate file into multiple files: https://maheshchandraregmi.com.np/splitting-a-big-tfstate-into-multiple-environments-with-remote-backend but I didn't get how one state file can read from another state file the configuration. I need this for lambda functions and  aws_iam_role and aws_iam_role_policy_attachment are part of aws_lambda_function.  Then I changed the pipeline Terraform step to: terraform plan -state=terraform.tfstate -but then because the resources are not anymore in the state file I get  "Error undeclared resource"

Comment: Either you store what you need the second terrafrom template in the config files/var files or you can use this:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs

Answer (score 0):

This is an AWS error. You don't show here but I guess you try to deploy both of you workspaces to the same AWS account. But due to that the AWS account already have resources named what you try to create with the second workspace it this fails.

See AWS docs here:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRole.html#:~:text=RoleName,MyResource%22%20and%20%22myresource%22](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRole.html#:%7E:text=RoleName,MyResource%22%20and%20%22myresource%22).